# Schedule notification when app is killed based on users calendar

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, notifications

I'm building a cordova app that [pulls a users agenda](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn911025(v=vs.120).aspx#OutlookServices).

I want to include a feature that sends the user a local notification when an event that is present in it's calendar, has ended.
Currently, I've done this by [scheduling local notifications](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/localNotification/) for every event the following month when a user opens the app, end updating this schedule every time he re-opens the app.

While this works flawlessly, it has an important restriction: let's say a user adds a new event (which is tomorrow) in his calendar via his computer, but doesn't open the app from now until the event. The app is killed on his phone, so there's no way my app can know it has to schedule a notification for this event.

How could I resolve this restriction? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need service for this, in your case even foreground service that every "X time" pulls user calendar events (in the background service) and updates/schedules local notifications each time.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Comment: Anything similar for cordova?